# install ros on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the install for kinetic for the raspberry pi 3.
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi
Its says if I have a raspberry pi 3 I can follow a easy method at:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

But I do not have a dedicated terminal and need to ssh into the raspberry from my pc. The instructions assume that I have ubuntu-mate on the raspberry, as far as I know there is no way to ssh into ubuntu-mate without first going into its desktop.

Are these instructions incorrect ... should ignore the easy recommendation and just follow the body of the instructors that follow in ROSberryPi. These instructions seem to work somewhat but there are issues accessing some of the packages that I have been unable to resolve. I am using realVNC(vncviewer) to ssh in to pi.

I am using 'catkin build'

I will re-flash my sdcard  with raspbian and go though the procedure again...but if anyone has some input please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260827/install-ros-on-raspberry-pi/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-05-02**:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/. Look for "headless".
If you use Raspbian you have to compile ROS. If you use Ubuntu Mate you can use the standard installation procedure. I don't know a way to activate SSH on a headless Ubuntu Mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu-mate does not support ssh from an initial install. ubuntu-mate requires a terminal for its desktop environment on initial boot.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0